# How to send to Oracle Parameters from C# Ado .NET?

Tags: c#, oracle

I try to send coil data from c# to ORACLE Database. But when i try to save all of this data I cant get any errors server side. All data looking like saved on the database but nothing happened. İnterestingly before then I could save all data in different part of project almost same way. Can you help that what was the mistake in that codes ? Although there is no mistake run time, why cant I save database these data?

```
public ActionResult SaveBobinDetails(AllBobinData allBobinData)
{
    using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(OracleHelper.DbConnect))
    {
        connection.Open();
        try
        {
            string storedProcedureName = "Z_TMP_PORTAL.save_qua_opr_data_detail";

            using (OracleCommand commandpiece = new OracleCommand(storedProcedureName, connection))
            { 
                commandpiece.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                commandpiece.CommandText = storedProcedureName; // Stored Procedure adını buraya yazın

                if (allBobinData.selectedValue == "TANDEM")
                {
                   
                         commandpiece.Parameters.Add("p_piece_id", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = allBobinData.p_piece_id;
                         commandpiece.Parameters.Add("p_op_data_id", OracleDbType.Int32).Value = Convert.ToInt32(allBobinData.p_op_data_id);
                         commandpiece.Parameters.Add("p_olculen_kalinlik_opr", OracleDbType.BinaryFloat).Value = Convert.ToDouble(allBobinData.oprkenarpltcm);
                         commandpiece.Parameters.Add("p_olculen_kalinlik_orta", OracleDbType.BinaryFloat).Value = Convert.ToDouble(allBobinData.ortakenarpltcm);
                         commandpiece.Parameters.Add("p_olculen_kalinlik_motor", OracleDbType.Int32).Value = Convert.ToDouble(allBobinData.mtrkenarpltcm);
                         commandpiece.Parameters.Add("p_olculen_genislik", OracleDbType.BinaryFloat).Value = Convert.ToDouble(allBobinData.genislikpltcm);
                         commandpiece.Parameters.Add("p_opr_kenar_dalgasi_yukseklik", OracleDbType.Int32).Value = Convert.ToInt32(allBobinData.p_opr_kenar_dalgasi_yukseklik);
                         commandpiece.Parameters.Add("p_opr_kenar_dalgasi_frekans", OracleDbType.Int32).Value = Convert.ToInt32(allBobinData.p_opr_kenar_dalgasi_frekans);
                         commandpiece.Parameters.Add("p_motor_kenar_dalgasi_yukseklik", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = Convert.ToInt32(allBobinData.p_motor_kenar_dalgasi_yukseklik);
                         commandpiece.Parameters.Add("p_motor_kenar_dalgasi_frekans", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = Convert.ToInt32(allBobinData.p_motor_kenar_dalgasi_frekans);
                         commandpiece.Parameters.Add("p_gobek_dalgasi_yukseklik", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = Convert.ToInt32(allBobinData.p_gobek_dalgasi_yukseklik);
                         commandpiece.Parameters.Add("p_gobek_dalgasi_frekans", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = Convert.ToInt32(allBobinData.p_gobek_dalgasi_frekans);

                }
                
                commandpiece.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

    }
    return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

ORACLE DATABASE CODES

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE save_qua_opr_data_detail (
    p_op_data_id                    IN NUMBER DEFAULT NULL,
    p_piece_id                      IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
    -- Diğer parametreler...
    p_operatör                      IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
    p_formen                        IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL
)
IS
    v_piece_count  NUMBER;
BEGIN
    
    CASE WHEN p_op_data_id IS NULL THEN
        INSERT INTO Z_TMP_PORTAL_QUA_OP_DATA (
            -- Sütunları buraya ekleyin
            -- Örnek: COLUMN_NAME
        )
        VALUES (
            -- Değerleri buraya ekleyin
            -- Örnek: p_piece_id
        );
    ELSE
        UPDATE
            Z_TMP_PORTAL_QUA_OP_DATA
        SET
            -- Güncellenecek sütunları ve değerlerini buraya ekleyin
            -- Örnek: COLUMN_NAME = p_value
        WHERE
            OP_DATA_ID = p_op_data_id;
    END CASE;
    
    
END save_qua_opr_data_detail;
```

Comment: This line _if (allBobinData.selectedValue == "TANDEM")_ Are you sure that is evaluated as "true"? Did you see with the debugger if the block following the line is really executed? If I am not wrong, the stored procedure assigns default values if there is no parameters passed, so this problem will probably not raise an Oracle error

Comment: i have  controlled with debug. İt is working on if code blocks and binding parameters.

Comment: Other possibilities are: 1) Wrong connection string? 2) What is the return value of ExecuteNonQuery? (it should be 1 if executed, 0 if not)

Comment: Have you disabled auto-commit? If so, are you `COMMIT`ting your query or is the session rolling back once you close the connection?

Answer (score 0):

This part does not look very smart:

```
if (allBobinData.selectedValue == "TANDEM")
{             
   commandpiece.Parameters.Add("p_piece_id", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = allBobinData.p_piece_id;
   ...
}
commandpiece.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

When selected value is not 'TANDEM', then the procedure is executed anyway - with parameter values from previous call. Is that what you like to do? Looks all parameters are defined with `DEFAULT NULL` which makes it a bit error prone.

Maybe try this style, it should be less error prone:

```
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("BEGIN save_qua_opr_data_detail(:p_piece_id, :p_op_data_id, ...); END;", connection);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.BindByName = true;
cmd.Parameters.Add("p_piece_id", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = allBobinData.p_piece_id;
cmd.Parameters.Add("p_op_data_id", OracleDbType.Int32).Value = Convert.ToInt32(allBobinData.p_op_data_id);
...
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

With `BindByName = true` the parameters are identified by name rather than by their position.

Even more secure would be this one:

```
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.BindByName = true;
cmd.Connection = connection;
cmd.Parameters.Add("p_piece_id", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = allBobinData.p_piece_id;
cmd.Parameters.Add("p_op_data_id", OracleDbType.Int32).Value = Convert.ToInt32(allBobinData.p_op_data_id);

List<string> pars = new List<string>();
foreach (var p in cmd.Parameters) {
   pars.Add(String.Format("{0} => :{0}", p.Name);
}
cmd.CommandText = (String.Format("BEGIN save_qua_opr_data_detail({0}); END;", string.Join(",", pars)), cmd))
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

(not tested, it is quite some time ago when I wrote my last C# program)

Answer (score 0):

Have set `connection.Autocommit = false`?

From the [`OracleCommand` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/odpnt/featOraCommand.html#GUID-9DD47FD2-56DB-42D4-94EA-E01E9F8C11CB):

> #### Command Auto-Commit
>
> By default, ODP.NET commits each SQL operation immediately upon execution outside of a transaction. Starting with 23c, managed ODP.NET and ODP.NET Core can disable auto-commit so that SQL statements are executed only after an explicit commit statement.
>
> Unmanaged ODP.NET cannot disable auto-commit without a transaction.
>
> Developers disable auto-commit by setting the `OracleConnection` `AutoCommit` property to false. ODP.NET can then start transactions implicitly. After the `AutoCommit` property is set, that setting is honored for all subsequent `Open()` calls on that specific OracleConnection object until the `AutoCommit` value is modified.

If you do not `COMMIT` the transaction then when the transaction is closed it will implicitly `ROLLBACK` any changes. If the transaction is left open then the changes will persist but will only be visible to the session that made those changes as uncommitted changes are not visible to other Oracle sessions (even those belonging to the same user).

Either ensure `connection.Autocommit = true` or else explicitly `COMMIT` the transaction after calling the stored procedure (best practice would be to do that in the code that calls the procedure, i.e. in C#, and not as part of the procedure as `COMMIT`ting in the procedure would prevent you from chaining multiple procedures together in a single transaction and then using `ROLLBACK` on them all if a later one fails).